# Registros repetidos en base de datos

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy trabajando con PHP. Tengo un formulario para ingreso de solicitudes. Cuando se ingresa un formulario el sistema envía un correo con PHPMailer con la información de la solicitud, todo eso funciona bien. Pero ingresando una solicitud observe un detalle que hasta ahora no he logrado resolver. Cuando presiono ENVIAR para crear una solicitud, el sistema tarda unos segundos en mostrar el mensaje que el registro fue ingresado, y en esos segundos de espera si yo presiono enviar nuevamente, el sistema crea nuevas solicitudes que se almacenan en la base de datos y también envía correo por cada vez que presione ENVIAR.
Me gustaría que alguien me pueda indicar como controlo y evito que un usuario envía varias veces la misma solicitud.

Les comparto mi código:

//MI FORMULARIO//

**Solicitar Pasantía**

```
    <div class="panel-body">
     <div class="col-md-12">
      <form method="post" action="ingresar_pasantia.php" class="clearfix">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon">
               <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
              </span>
           </div>
          </div>
  
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-5">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></i>
                  </span>
                    <input type="text" name="nombre_docente" placeholder="Nombres">>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-5">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></i>
                  </span>
                    <input type="text" name="apellido_docente" placeholder="Apellidos">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></i>
                  </span>
                  <input type="text" name="rut" placeholder="Rut" maxlength="10">
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-5">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i>
                    </span>
                    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail">
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <button type="submit" name="ingresar_pasantia">Enviar</button>
          <a href="pasantia.php" class="btn btn-primary">Mis Solicitudes</a>
      </form>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

// GUARDAR REGISTRO EN BASE DE DATOS //

```
 if(isset($_POST['ingresar_pasantia']))
 {
   $req_fields = array('nombre_docente','apellido_docente','rut','email');
   validate_fields($req_fields);
   if(empty($errors))
   {
     $nombre_docente  = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['nombre_docente']));
     $apellido_docente  = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['apellido_docente']));
     $rut   = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['rut']));
     $email   = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['email']));

     $query  = "INSERT INTO pasantia (";
     $query .=" nombre_docente, apellido_docente, rut, email";
     $query .=") VALUES (";
     $query .=" '{$nombre_docente}','{$apellido_docente}','{$rut}','{$email}'";
     $query .=")";
     $query .=" ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE nombre_docente='{$nombre_docente}'";

     if($db->query($query))
     {
       $session->msg('s',"Solicitud ingresada exitosamente. ");
       redirect('ingresar.php', false);
       unlink($path);
     } 
     else 
     {
       $session->msg('d',' Lo siento, registro falló.');
       redirect('prod.php', false);
     }
   } 
   else
   {
     $session->msg("d", $errors);
     redirect('ingresar.php',false);
   }
}
```

Comment: Qué tal deshabilitar el botón en el momento en que se hace click?

Comment: Gracias por responder, que función podría ocupar para eso??

Comment: Qué palabras utilizaste en google? Yo busqué "deshabilitar botón stack overflow" y [varios enlaces](https://letmegooglethat.com/?q=stack+overflow+deshabiilitar+bot%C3%B3n&l=1) me funcionaron bien

Comment: Actualice la pregunta, agregue una función que encontré, pero al presionar el botón se logra deshabilitar pero no guarda el formulario

Comment: Pues, no sé qué decirte. Sólo copiaste y pegaste? La idea detrás de mi sugerencia es: *"poner un event listener en el botón de guardado, que desactive el botón y haga el submit al form"*. No veo que controles el evento `click` del botón. En tu código, `event` no está definido. De donde viene?

Comment: Te agradezco tu orientación, la verdad no soy un experto en programación y hay algunas cosas que no entiendo mucho, pero gracias.. buscaré según lo que me dices.

Comment: Más allá de desactivar bien o mal el botón, deberías asegurar que tu lógica de negocio no inserte registros repetidos. Por qué no validas a nivel de base de datos que si cierto valor se repite (o si cierto conjunto de columnas se repite), no inserte? Eso sería un UNIQUE constraint. Si soy un usuario malo, pues me salto la interfaz y mando la petición desde postman y te lleno de mugre la BD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo resolvi con la siguiente funcion:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(e){
    
        $("[name='ingresar_pasantia']").click(function(){
            $(this).attr("disabled","disabled");
        });
   
  });   
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Si el problema es con el **disabled**, yo no suelo utilizarlo, este atributo deshabilita por completo el elemento, hace como si no existiera, en este caso se lo estamos asignando aun botón en un formulario, lo que hace que no cumpla con su función y también la de los elementos anteriores, en este caso los inputs de información, esto si funcionaria si lo hiciéramos con Ajax en **beforesend**. AHORA LA MODIFICACIÓN LA HACEMOS DESDE CSS, AGREGAMOS UNA CLASE AL HACER EL SUBMIT DEL FORM DESABILITANDO LOS CURSORES:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form").on("submit", function() {
    //AGREGAMOS UNA CLASE PARA DESABILITAR DESDE CSS
    $("[name='ingresar_pasantia']").addClass('sinEvento');
  });
});
```

```css
.sinEvento {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  background-color: rgb(229, 229, 229) !important;
}

.sinEvento>* {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-body">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <form method="post" action="ingresar_pasantia.php" class="clearfix">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></i>
              </span>
              <input type="text" name="nombre_docente" placeholder="Nombres">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></i>
              </span>
              <input type="text" name="apellido_docente" placeholder="Apellidos">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></i>
              </span>
              <input type="text" name="rut" placeholder="Rut" maxlength="10">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i>
              </span>
              <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" name="ingresar_pasantia" id="send">Enviar</button>
      <a href="pasantia.php" class="btn btn-primary">Mis Solicitudes</a>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

DIME SI ES LA BUENA.

Comment: Efectivamente deshabilita el botón, pero el formulario no se envía y además ya no valida los campos required.

Comment: actualice la pregunta con una función que si permite el envío del formulario y se deshabilita, pero lo hace al segundo clic y no inmediatamente al presionar enviar

Comment: He modificado mi respuesta, deshabilita el botón y envía el formulario.

Comment: Continua sin enviar el formulario, se deshabilita y se carga nuevamente la pagina.

Comment: Si el problema es con el **disabled**, yo no suelo utilizarlo, este atributo deshabilita por completo el elemento, hace como si no existiera, en este caso se lo estamos asignando aun botón en un formulario, lo que hace que no cumpla con su función y también la de los elementos anteriores, en este caso los inputs de informacion, esto si funcionaria si lo hiciéramos  con Ajax en **beforesend**. Lo que podemos hacer es remplazar el elemento, modifique de nuevo mi respuesta.

Comment: Sigue ocurriendo lo mismo, deshabilita el botón pero no guarda el formulario.

Comment: Modifique de nuevo la respuesta, ahora hagamoslo con css.

Comment: Probé el código, pero no deshabilita el botón, lo cambia el estilo

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138128/discussion-between-antonio-galicia-and-sbk22).